# how to redirect url with parameters using htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to change my url using htaccess file.

my url is : `http://localhost/shasi/payment-result?Authority=000000000000000000000000000023436395&Status=NOK`

and i want to redirect my page to this url : `http://localhost/shasi/payment-result/Authority/000000000000000000000000000023436395/Status/NOK`

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Authority=([0-9]+)&Status=([^/]+)$`

`RewriteRule ^payment-result /payment-result/Authority/%1/Status/%2  [R=301,L,NC]`